# How to write a long table in a short summarized table dropping some variables, the values of which are repeated?

Tags: r, crosstab, data-management

First, sorry for the unclear title. But I couldn't think of anything else at this point of time. Suppose i have the data similar to following-

```
Name    Type    Year
ABC     ABC-1   2000
ABC     ABC-1   2001
ABC     ABC-1   2002
ABC     ABC-2   2000
ABC     ABC-2   2002
DEF     DEF-1   2001
DEF     DEF-1   2002
DEF     DEF-2   2000
DEF     DEF-2   2001
DEF     DEF-3   2004
```

Now I don't want to bother about the `year` variable. I want the data to be of the following form-

## Expected Format

```
Name    Type
ABC     ABC-1
ABC     ABC-2
DEF     DEF-1
DEF     DEF-2
DEF     DEF-3
```

I tried some combination of `table`, `ftable`. But I can't get them as I want. Can you guys help me? Thanks !!

Comment: `unique(df[, c(1,2)])`, where `df` is your data frame.

Comment: is `df` the name of the `dataframe` ?

Comment: Hi, @Psidom, it worked. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `duplicated`

```
df[!duplicated(df[1:2]),-3]
#  Name  Type
#1   ABC ABC-1
#4   ABC ABC-2
#6   DEF DEF-1
#8   DEF DEF-2
#10  DEF DEF-3
```